# How do i use removeEventListener to remove event?

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<button id="btn" value="250">Click Me</button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',say,false);

function say() {
 alert("this is add function !!!");
 this.removeEventListener('click',function () {
  alert("this is remove function");
  },false);
}
```

I want that functionality on my button that if user click first time than alert box show "this is add function" but second time click than alert bix show "this is remove function" & third time again show "this is a add function" , this will continue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener ... instead of adding/removing event handlers, you can just keep a counter and show the right message depending on the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to remove the eventlistener, just to change the text of the alert - in both alarms you need an event listener on the click.

you can keep a flag or something

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',say,false);
var showAddText = true;
function say() {
    var alertText = showAddText ? 'this is add function' : 'this is remove function'
    showAddText = !showAddText;
    alert(alertText);
}
```

if you want to practice removeEventListener -

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',say,false);
function say() {
    alert('this is add function');
    document.getElementById('btn').removeEventListener('click',say,false);
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',say2,false);
} 
function say2(){
    alert('this is remove function');
    document.getElementById('btn').removeEventListener('click',say2,false);
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',say,false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter isntead of adding and removing event listeners.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',say,false);
var ctr = 0;
function say() {
  if(ctr%2 == 0) {
     ctr = 1;
     alert("this is add function !!!");
  }
  else {
    ctr= 0;
    
    alert("this is remove function");
  }
 
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" value="250">Click Me</button>
```